# Getting access to iframe contents with jquery after inspecting it with the browser

Tags: jquery, same-origin-policy

A curious thing happened today testing a website I am developing: I was attempting to get access to elements inside an iframe with jquery, and to my surprise **I was able to access them and modify them**. The surprise is because the iframe is not on the same domain, thus I was not supposed to be able to do that for "same origin policy" (or I'm I wrong?).

Thing is, it could only be done after "inspecting" any iframe's element with the browser (chrome in this case). If later I "inspect" any element of the site not inside the iframe, then I lose that "superpower" and get the expected result, i.e. jquery not allowed to access due to "same origin policy".

The questions: 
1.- Is that supposed to happen?
2.- Is there a way to prevent it if it could imply security risks?
3.- If this is suppose to happen and is safe, how can I jquery "simulate" the browser "inspecting" so that I can get access to iframes elements and modify them

Comment: Were you running the jquery in the console?

Comment: Yes, the test described was from chrome's console

Comment: In the console you can select which frame level you want your javascript to be run in. So you can run the jQuery within any iframe within the page regardless of the origin. If you are sure you were running the javascript in the *top* frame and from there accessing a different origin iframe, then that would be unexpected (I'd have to try to replicate it myself to gather more information).

Comment: I  think i see what you mean, but just to be sure: more specifically: I first "inspected" an element inside the iframe, from there on I could modify elements inside iframe with jquery from the browser's console. Then I "inspected" some element outside the iframe (some other place in the site), then i was not able to modify iframe's elements from the same console

Comment: That's correct. When you inspect an iframe, the console automatically switches the context to that of the iframe. On the top of the console there's a little dropdown (by default it says "top", but if you inspect another iframe it will change to that iframe's name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inspect an iframe (tested on Chrome), it automatically sets the context of the console to be that of the iframe. So you can then run any javascript directly on the contents of the iframe. But it would not be able to access it from the parent-level (where the iframe was instantiated), as such actions could be seen as a security flaw.

Here's an example when you try to access on the parent context (in this case the parent is jsfiddle's iframe as yo ucan see in the top left):
[image: Accessing from parent context]

And then when I switch the context to the iframe I was trying to access:
[image: Accessing from the iframe's context]

Hope this summarizes the answer and can help anyone else that might have a similar question.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for your patience and your time. To paraphrase your text as responses to my questions:

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for your patience and your time. To paraphrase your text as responses to my questions:  Response 1.- Yes, it is suppose to happen but only in browser's console, not for coded js or jquery. Response 2.- There is no need to prevent it since it can only be done manually from a browser's console (it is safe). 3.- You cannot jquery "simulate" the browser "inspecting" to get access to iframes elements and modify them.